# SQL COUNT only display results once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My simple query is as follows in SQL Server Management Studio 2012:-

```
SELECT Last_Name, City,
(SELECT COUNT (City) FROM Customers IX WHERE IX.City = EX.City) as counting
FROM Customers EX
GROUP BY City, Last_Name
ORDER BY City
```

Outputs this:-

```
Last_Name   City    Counting
Joe     London  3
Smith   London  3
Carter  London  3
Stones  New York    3
Jones   New York    3
White   New York    3
```

But I would like it to not repeat the counts for the same city and output like this:-

```
Last_Name   City    Counting
Joe     London  3
Smith   London  
Carter  London  
Stones  New York    3
Jones   New York    
White   New York
```

How would I achieve this please?

Comment: You should "achieve" this in a presentation layer, not in the database layer

Comment: I don't think this is something you can specify in a database query. A query results in a fix number of columns and rows, and every single cell should have a value. As Lamak suggested, you better do this in the presentation layer.

Even if this is possible, it adds a huge amount of unnecessary complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a very odd request, and easily done on the application side.  But it is not that hard in SQL:

```
SELECT Last_Name, City,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by Last_Name, City order by (select NULL)) = 1
             then (SELECT COUNT(City) FROM Customers IX WHERE IX.City = EX.City) as counting
        end) as Counting
FROM Customers EX
GROUP BY City, Last_Name
ORDER BY City;
```

This will put the value on one row for each city.  It is not determinate which one, but would probably be the first in practice.  You can guarantee this by using a stable sort:

```
SELECT Last_Name, City,
       (case when row_number() over (partition by Last_Name, City order by Last_Name) = 1
             then (SELECT COUNT(City) FROM Customers IX WHERE IX.City = EX.City) as counting
        end) as Counting
FROM Customers EX
GROUP BY City, Last_Name
ORDER BY City, Last_Name
```

Comment: It's less that it's hard and has more to do with it being a silly request.